# How to logout / close ssh connection after completing session

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing, ssh

I don't have any experience of using ssh / commands, I'm using ssh just for reindexing Magento.

When I finish reindexing then how can I log out? Which command can I use to log out?

Comment: simply type **`exit`** and hit enter.

Comment: Try to find answer [here: "How do I exit an SSH connection?"](http://superuser.com/questions/467398/how-do-i-exit-an-ssh-connection)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this question is not about Magento

Comment: It's my pleasure :)